# Add Custom Button to Sharepoint 2013 List Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In a Sharepoint 2013 list of items, is it possible to add a couple of columns that feature my own custom action buttons?  These buttons would be on each list item (row) and perform an action specific to that row.  And I'm sure it's not possible, but will Sharepoint allow NO labels for their column headers?

The caveat is that the powers-that-be may not want to see fields for those two extra columns in the New or Edit forms for that list.

Please bear with me on what must be a totally noob question.  I am a designer with very elementary knowledge of Sharepoint that has been thrown to the Sharepoint wolves, so to speak.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you as much.

If you want to make a change before saving, you can insert a javascript on the form you desire.

Before saving the Sharepoint runs a javascript code with "PreSaveAction" function, eg PreSaveAction function () {your code; return true}

Do not forget to put return true or return false. You will return true place to save and return false to not save.

The cancel button or close the form performs no function but can insert a javascript button manually.

I use Sharepoint Designer 2013 to open Sharepoint, and after that open the desired form. After opening the form will contain two Sharepoint Button. You can make a display: none a button and insert a button with your javascript function.

Anything I am available to help you.